# Multiple interactive iframe content in colorbox or fancybox

Tags: iframe, fancybox, colorbox

I am an absolute newbie in JS and Ajax,after going through both fancybox and colorbox I'm unable to achieve a slideshow with 'prev' and 'next option  to navigate between the iframes that I'm trying to load within my html under banner.

In fancybox the height couldn't be adjusted ( although I tried various options including editing the jquery.fancybox.css directly under .fancybox-wrap with !important ,etc

I was never able to get the prev & next button working although they were under the same folder as the css

the iframe content is a panaromic flash content with (3 different).index html which I've been able to load a within an iframe but when trying to load multiple htmlfiles as slide show or with scroll prev & next option it doesn't work.
bellow is my call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.iframe").fancybox({
        'width' : 1000,
        'height' : 500,
        'autoScale' : false,
        'transitionIn' : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'type' : 'iframe' 
    });
});

<!-- html code here -->

<a class="iframe" href="360/type1/example.html"><img src="images/type1.png" height="100" width="100"/></a>
<a class="iframe" href="360/type2/example.html"><img src="images/type2.png" height="100" width="100"/></a>
</body>
```

Comment: what version of fancybox?

Comment: hi I'm using version 2

Comment: ps: i also tried the above with a rel"gallery" but not sure if it was the right approach ,though didn't work, i read most of the comments by you including the one that was pointed out in google with a 'callsite' option ..bit confused after various attempt,thanks JFK,I'm hoping you could show me a way

Comment: does this help? http://jsfiddle.net/JZUCU/

Comment: going to try now ,will comment soon,thank you

Comment: not successful yet ,no error found either under chrome's console ...will keep trying and let you know.I mean I had a success before with 1 html which was hanging in the middle with a width of aprox 1200 and heights of 350 aprox which i believe is the default one but couldn't get it to show the nav button or adjust the height prev.Well I'm sure it's gotta work somehow..clue is how ,thank for your kind help